# Passing an integer to a method

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to pass a simple integer of type int to a void method which looks like this:

```
-(void)deleteGroup{
```

I know I should do something like:

```
[self deleteGroup withInt: 3];
```

But I can't seem to figure out the correct solution

Comment: Oh noez! Tried learning Objective-C from a tutorial? Doesn't seem so. How'bout `deleteGroup:(int)x`?

Comment: I mean the following to be helpful - please step back and learn the basics of C and Objective-C. This is a truly basic Objective-C question about having arguments in a method signature. Based on all of the questions you ask, you seem to be coding your app by asking SO to help with everything. You really need to take time to learn the basics first. At least do some searching before asking such basic questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to change

```
-(void)deleteGroupWithInteger:(NSInteger)intValue{
```

Then use

```
[self deleteGroupWithInteger:3];
```

Comment: you are always very patient and understanding.

Comment: @HalR Apropos of nothing, that sounded like a fortune cookie. +1

Comment: @HalR Way more patient than necessary (and than me). +1.